# What's the time complexity of prod() in math in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, time-complexity, product

**Summary)**

1. What's the time complexity of `math.prod()`
2. How to improve this code to get to the pass

**Details)**

Currently working on 'Product of Array Except Self' on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/submissions/)

*My first code was:*

```
class Solution:
    def productExceptSelf(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        product_list = []

        for index in range(len(nums)):
            deleted_value = nums.pop(index)
            product_list.append(math.prod(nums))
            nums.insert(index, deleted_value)
            
        return product_list
```

and thought it was 'delete and insert' in a dynamic array causing problems with the time limit.

*So, I corrected some lines to:*

```
class Solution:
    def product_except_self(self, nums):
        product_list = []

        for index in range(len(nums)):
            temp = nums[index]
            nums[index] = 1
            product_list.append(math.prod(nums))
            nums[index] = temp

        return product_list
```

As far as I'm concerned, ' = ' and append operation has the time complexity of O(1), so thinking that math.prod is the one posing problems here, except 'for' which is O(n).

Please enlighten me about the time complexity here and some tips to get a pass on this question.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's almost definitely O(n); Appending is O(1), but amortized over many calls. It depends on the implementation but a few of the calls are going to have to reallocate larger memory and copy everything that exists so far into the new space.
2. The point of these challenges is to get you to think of the better approach you could take, and practice learning to recognize how you think about the usual approach and the paths that take you to the better one so that you will be able to do that kind of thinking more easily on a non-trivial problem. That said: You could calculate the full array product once only, then divide that product by each array element to produce the results. Use a generator or list comprehension.

Comment: It is mentioned in the problem that we cannot use division.

Comment: `prod` is only O(n) if multiplication is O(1). That's not a good assumption here because the result will generally be an integer of size O(n) bits. It's not simple to say what the time complexity will be in theory because it depends on the algorithm used for multiplying integers (I think CPython uses Karatsuba multiplication) and the algorithm used by `prod` (e.g. divide and conquer will beat the naive algorithm, because it does most of its multiplications with smaller numbers rather than larger ones).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get around the time limit is to store values and their products in a hash table so you can quickly answer instead of computing that value again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35331483)